# php socket functions error return values not correct

Tags: php, function, sockets

I keep getting error returns from `socket_create` and `socket_connect` function calls but when I do `socket_strerror(socket_last_error($soc))` I get **"Success"** as the return value. What's going on?

**Code:**

```
function conserver($sw) { 
    socket_clear_error(); 
    $ip = lookuphost($sw); 
    if(empty($ip)) 
     return socket_strerror(socket_last_error($soc))." "."DNS error<br>";
    socket_clear_error(); 
    $soc = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, SOL_TCP);
    socket_clear_error($soc); 
    if(!socket_connect($soc, $ip, 10123)) 
        return socket_strerror(socket_last_error($soc))." "."connect error<br>";
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you are referring to? It will help us figure out what is wrong.

Comment: function conserver($sw)
{
        socket_clear_error();
        $ip = lookuphost($sw);
        if(empty($ip))
                return socket_strerror(socket_last_error($soc))." "."DNS error<br>";

        socket_clear_error();
        $soc = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, SOL_TCP);
        socket_clear_error($soc);
        if(!socket_connect($soc, $ip, 10123))
                return socket_strerror(socket_last_error($soc))." "."connect error<br>";

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I don't know how to fix that.